# How do i check inBetween time using time zone Moment

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I'm trying to get time in between but it's not working. it always say "Not a business time!"

```
 let currentTime = moment().tz('Europe/London');
      let opening = moment('9:00am', 'h:mma');
      let closing = moment('7:00pm', 'h:mma');
      console.log(currentTime);
      console.log(opening);
      console.log(closing);

      if (currentTime.isBetween(opening,closing)) {

      openText = "It's business time!"

    } else {

      openText = "Not a business time!"

    }
```

Console Output

```
moment.parseZone("2017-08-20T16:57:06.117+01:00")
moment("2017-08-20T09:00:00.000")
moment("2017-08-20T19:00:00.000")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you lib version is `2.9.0+` [reference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)

Make sure to include:

1. moment.js
2. moment-timezone.js
3. moment-timezone-with-data.js

Working Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/guw1s31q/1/